# I have tried EVERYTHING.. My form wont post to database..

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have tried rewrite the code, i have looked on previously succesful codings i have made and i really cant find the problem.. i am going crazy.

I am trying to post some data from a form to a database.

The database i setup correctly as far as i can tell, but something is making the script fail every time.

IMAGE OF DATABASE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9ciJ.jpg

(sry for the language being in danish.)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>


<?php

// defining database information

define("HOSTNAME", "localhost");
define("MYSQLUSER", "admin");
define("MYSQLPASS", "admin");
define("MYSQLDB", "lynx");

// establishing database connection

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $connection = new mysqli(HOSTNAME, MYSQLUSER, MYSQLPASS, MYSQLDB);
    
    
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['name']);
    $price = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['price']);
    $desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['desc']);
    
    $insert = "INSERT into products (id, name, price, desc) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$price', '$desc')";
    
    if($connection->query($insert)) {
        echo "Succes";
    } else {
        echo "Something went wrong";
    }
    
}

?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="price">
    <input type="text" name="desc">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
    
</form>

    
</body>
</html>
```

Can you see what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Obviously, you haven't tried *EVERYTHING*.  `desc` is a reserved word in SQL.  You should change the name of the column or enclose it in backticks.

Comment: And your query is vulnerable to MySQL injections. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: The main thing you haven't _tried_ is adding error checking to your code. It's likely that `$connection->query()` fails. You can fetch a descriptive error with `$connection->error`.

Comment: @BenPearlKahan OP is using `mysqli`, not `mysql`.

Comment: but i had no idea that was a reserved word.. even my teacher didnt know o.O

Comment: change desc field to something else. It will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
products (id, name, price, desc)
```

Tried reading the manual as well? `desc` is a **[reserved word](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.mysql.com%2Fdoc%2Frefman%2F5.5%2Fen%2Freserved-words.html&ei=FtFdVb7dBczuUMefgbgM&usg=AFQjCNHDCsWr5ITTBAsj-XvPWMaC1Rxi7A&bvm=bv.93756505,d.d24)**.

If you didnt have this useless piece of code

```
else {
        echo "Something went wrong";
     }
```

and had

```
else {
        echo $connection-error;
     }
```

You would find that out yourself

Comment: no i havent xD im getting lectures in php at my university, and he couldnt find the issue with the coding.. ill try it! XD

Comment: Wow!! thank you so much sir! guess ill have to give my teacher a lesson then. you saved my day sir!

Comment: Whenever something doesn't work like you want it to, first check for error messages and not have your own custom messages. Once you know what's wrong then you can modify them. Displaying the right error message saves you from headache and tells exactly what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

`desc` is reverse keyword of mysql you can use it using `backtick`

```
$insert = "INSERT into products (`id`, `name`, `price`, `desc`) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$price', '$desc')";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is with your field 'desc' . this is not allowed by MYSQL because it is reserved. So please rename it. It will solve your issue.